# Rails - feedjira get last n news

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

Is there a method of `feedjira` that gets the last n news from an RSS feed?
(I have looked over the API but I could find anything similar).

Is there another way of getting the last n news with `feedjira`?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that `feedjira` has an option for limiting the number of results. For now, you'll probably need to just limit them yourself. Something like:

```
limit   = 5
feed    = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse('http://velocitylabs.io/feed.xml')
entries = feed.entries[0..(limit-1)]
```

> Be aware that the `fetch_and_parse` method is inconsistent in it's return values, if it is not successful, so you may need some checks around that.
>
> e.g., it return 0 if the URL param is a string, a hash if the URL param is an array

You might also consider [submitting an issue and pull request](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/issues) to the project :)